# Split string with regex separator except when separator is escaped

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a code (consider 'Z' as escape character, and ',' as separator):

```
import re

a = 'aaa,bbbZ,cccZZ,dddZZZ,eee'
print re.split(r'(?<!Z)[,]+', a)
```

Result is:

> ['aaa', 'bbbZ,cccZZ,dddZZZ,eee']

But I need the result processed escaped sequences (in my example escape char is 'Z'):

> ['aaa', 'bbbZ,cccZZ', 'dddZZZ,eee']

When I try to use variable width pattern for negative lookbehind assertion:

```
print re.split(r'(?<!(ZZ)*Z)[,]+', a)
```

it says:

> sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: Please first state *what you want to do*. Not *how* you do it...

Comment: My target is in the title

Comment: but there is no escaping at all...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem _"escape char is 'Z'"_ Think of the Z as a backslash if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may match the sequences with a pattern that will either match any chars that are not a comma, or any 1+ commas preceded with odd number of `Z`s:

```
import re
a = 'aaa,bbbZ,cccZZ,dddZZZ,eee'
print(re.findall(r'(?:(?<!Z)Z(?:ZZ)*,+|[^,])+', a))
# => ['aaa', 'bbbZ,cccZZ', 'dddZZZ,eee']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/l5t8pM) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m375IT/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:(?<!Z)Z(?:ZZ)*,+|[^,])+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `(?<!Z)Z` - a `Z` not immediately preceded with `Z`
  - `(?:ZZ)*` - zero or more  sequences of `ZZ`
  - `,+` - 1 or more commas
  - `|` - or
  - `[^,]` - any char that is not a comma

With a [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/), you may use `regex.split` method with a `(?<=(?<!Z)(?:ZZ)*),+` regex:

```
import regex
a = 'aaa,bbbZ,cccZZ,dddZZZ,eee'
print(regex.split(r'(?<=(?<!Z)(?:ZZ)*),+', a))
#  ['aaa', 'bbbZ,cccZZ', 'dddZZZ,eee']
```

See [another online Python demo](http://rextester.com/DBH14209).

Here, the pattern matches 1 or more commas (`,+`) that are preceded with any 0+ sequences of `ZZ` that are not preceded with another `Z` (that is, with an even number of `Z`).

Comment: @Symon: Only with PyPi regex module.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: I suggest: `(?:Z.)*(*SKIP)\K,+` for `regex.split` and `(?=[^,])[^,Z]*(?:Z.[^,Z]*)*Z?` for `re.findall`